# node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(710,25): error TS1005: ',' expected while running typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, lodash, ethereum

I am trying to run https://github.com/scorelab/EtherBeat locally i have installed all dependecies now when I run npm start
I get the following error

```
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1220,223): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,42): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,72): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,86): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,109): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,123): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,151): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,195): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,204): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,205): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,237): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,313): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1224,384): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,42): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,72): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,86): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,109): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,123): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,161): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,205): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,215): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,216): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1228,288): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1232,17): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1232,46): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1232,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1232,80): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2078,126): error TS1005: '>' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2078,138): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2078,159): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2078,174): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2078,175): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,26): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,56): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,57): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,68): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,96): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,121): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,125): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,160): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,192): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2082,211): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2083,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2098,131): error TS1005: '>' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2098,143): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2098,164): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2098,179): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2098,180): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,26): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,56): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,57): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,73): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,101): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,126): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,130): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,165): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,197): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2102,216): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2103,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,47): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,72): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,75): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,120): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,123): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,132): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,133): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2221,134): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2222,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,52): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,77): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,80): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,93): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,125): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,128): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,137): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,138): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2227,139): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2228,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2246,49): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2246,74): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2246,77): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2246,90): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2246,122): error TS1005
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2330,33): error TS1005: '>' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2330,61): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2330,79): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2330,82): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2330,83): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2331,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2519,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(87,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(87,50): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(155,61): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(155,69): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(156,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(165,70): error TS1005: '>' expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(165,78): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(165,126): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(166,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(1220,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(20,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
```

C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\mySpace\blockchaindata\etherbeat>

I have already tried changing typescript version and also the version of different dependencies,
still getting the error.

Someone help me on this.

Comment: just update the lodash and typescript to the latest version and the error will be gone.

Comment: Upgrading npm typescript dependency from version 3 to ^4.9.5 fixed this for me